# How do you put a comma in thousands separator in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a problem to put a comma in thousands separator in WPF. The numbers are in textboxes so whenever a number is entered it should display that way. I tried StringFormat but it didn't work.

```
  <TextBox Text="{Binding ParcelDetails.OverrideTotalFloorArea.Value,StringFormat='\{0:$#,##0\}', Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, ValidatesOnExceptions= False}"  
                                             IsEnabled="{Binding ParcelDetails.OverrideTotalFloorArea.IsEnabled, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                             Visibility="{Binding ParcelDetails.OverrideTotalFloorArea.IsVisible, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}"
                                             Margin="15,2,3,3" 
                                             Width="130" >
```

Comment: I don't know whether there is any default implementation for this but you can create a converter and use it for the same..

Comment: Your StringFormat should look like this: `0:C` this will use current culture info so make sure you are using correct one. Your code has fixed values for width and margin, these are usually a bad sign.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just posting a sample Converter for you. You can edit or optimize the code accrodingly.

```
public class Converter : IValueConverter
    {
        public static Converter Instance { get; } = new Converter();

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            decimal a;
            string val = System.Convert.ToString(value);
            if (decimal.TryParse(val,out a))
            {
                var index = val.IndexOf('.');
                if (index>3)
                {
                    val = val.Insert(index - 3, ",");
                    return val;
                }
            }
            return "";
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
```